# CarrierWave with custom processor not registering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, carrierwave

I am using [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) to upload a video then have a version called thumb with a custom processor that takes the video and creates a screenshot using streamio-ffmpeg.  Both the video and the file are uploaded correctly but when calling uploader.url(:thumb) I get:

> ArgumentError: Version thumb doesn't exist!

### VideoUploader.rb

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'

class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::VideoConverter
    include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

    process :set_content_type

    storage :file

    version :thumb do
            process :create_thumb

            #def full_filename(for_file)
            #        "thumb_#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.png"
            #end
    end

    def create_thumb
            cached_stored_file! if !cached?

            movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(current_path)

            dirname = File.dirname(current_path)

            thumb_path = "#{File.join(dirname, File.basename(path, File.extname(path)))}.png"

            movie.screenshot(thumb_path, :seek_time => 5)
            File.rename thumb_path, current_path
    end

    def file_identifier
            model[:video]
    end

    # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
    # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
    def store_dir
            return "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.user_id}/#{model.id}"
    end
end
```

Then model.video_url(:thumb) returns the argument error.  I am not sure what to do or why the version isn't registered any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: just try recreating a version and then check using `[model object].video.recreate_versions!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fix

What contributed to the error was a mix of restarting the server but not restarting the rails console.  Once i did this the Argument error went away but I was getting the wrong path.  So i uncommented

```
        def full_filename(for_file)
                "thumb_#{File.basename(for_file, File.extname(for_file))}.png"
        end
```

and used

```
[model].video.recreate_versions!
```

to correct any errors in the paths or naming schemes that could have occured

Answer (score 0):

most likely some step in your create_thumb method is failing and thus the thumb is never created and has no URL. Are there any exceptions being thrown to your logs?

Perhaps you need to specify the FFMPEG binary location:

```
FFMPEG.ffmpeg_binary = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
```

Comment: This is not the case since both the video file and the png file are created and stored correctly.  There is no error on the creation or uploading of files.  If I am doing something wrong on what i'm returning in create_thumb though please inform me what to change